# What is the meaning of this sentence? "no concern"

Tags: meaning

> I think we have **no concern** to provide the report of your performance.

Does it mean that they are willing to write a report or not?

Comment: It could go either way. In either case, it's not the clearest use of English I've ever seen.

Comment: The corporate world, its own politics, uses extra words to hide meaning. *I think we have no concern* is padding that hides whether *We* will or will not provide that darn report.

Comment: It's an acknowledged usage: From [Hansard, 2008](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm200506/cmhansrd/vo060123/debtext/60123-22.htm): << Mr. Gummer: I wonder whether it is reasonable to remind the House that those of us who represent English constituencies but come from Welsh stock also have a concern to promote the best possible government for Wales, and have no concern to remove the devolution arrangement, which is now part of our history. >> But I don't know and can't find what it means (I'd guess 'we have no intentions of').

Comment: I'm with Edwin: there is no agenda to make *the* report (that was already written) available.